# Is it a good idea to always use the Java Beans naming conventions?

Tags: java, naming-conventions, javabeans

I have always found it very useful to adhere to the Java Beans naming conventions: `getX()`, `setX()`, `isX()`, etc. I think the Java Bean naming conventions provide several main advantages:

1. When looking through code, you can immediately determine the purpose of a method.
2. When looking through the API documentation, all methods are grouped together due to the alphabetical ordering of the Java documentation.
3. When using the code completion feature of any IDE, it is easy and intuitive to sort through and find the method that you are looking for. This is again due to the alphabetical ordering of the IDE.

I know that there are many classes that are part of the Java API that do not use the Java Beans naming conventions. An example would be `ArrayList`, which has methods such as `size()`.

I actually have two main questions:

1. Is it a good idea to always try to use the Java Beans naming conventions? If not, why?
2. I know that `ArrayList` was written before Java Beans came out. Is it customary for Oracle to use the Java Beans naming conventions for all (or at least most) new content?

---

**The below is more to get people to think rather than an actual question.**

As I stated above, I have always stuck with the Java Bean naming conventions. I think they provide a lot of advantages in a lot of ways. I think the biggest problem is that without Java Beans, a lot of people use confusing naming conventions

I *personally believe* that the following should always be adhered to, and I'm curious to see what people think about it:

1. If the method name is a noun, the method is expected to return a value.
2. If the method name is a verb, the method should always do something. If the method returns a value, the returned value should be related to the action that was performed.
3. If the method name is an adjective, the name should not be used alone. For example, `big()` should be `isBig()`.
4. Nouns that are not an implicit property of an object should not be used alone.

   For example:

   `size()` is an appropriate method of a `House` object, but `door()` is not. The reason for this is that `size` is an inherit property of a `house` that was decided by nature. It is not physically required for a `house` to have a `door`.

   Instead of `door()`, the method should be named `getDoor()`.
5. If the method name adheres to multiple parts of speech, the method is always going to require unnecessary thinking from the users end. Because of this, the method should probably be rename.

   For example:

   Let's say I have a method called `profile()`. Depending on the class it is part of, `profile()` might be a verb or a noun. I could be profiling something, or I could be getting the profile. Changing the name of the method to `getProfile()` or `doProfiling()` would add clarification.

Comment: I would say that this will generate a certain amount of personal opinion.  Personally, I prefer to use the bean naming convention as I've grown accustom to it, so when I want to try and "get" or "set" a value, these are the method signatures I begin my search with. Is it customary for Oracle/Sun to follow these conventions with newer APIs, I'd say not really, which is kind of shame

Comment: Classes have each word capitalized (eg. ArrayList).

Comment: Great question, too opinion-based :/

First time I've given an upvote and a flag...

Comment: The standard Java library is full of inconsistencies in this regard and don't count on it that new classes and interfaces will adhere to any standard.

Comment: New classes introduced in Java 9 would seem to have abandoned JavaBeans naming conventions:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ModuleLayer.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you adhere to the naming conventions between varibles and getter/setter methods it also enables you to use tools that rely on those conventions like BeanUtils and Spring. While changing the names to be more readable, you may lose the ability to use api that help relieve "boilerplate" code.